# Please help me with the following proof on sigma field

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$, $\mathcal{C}$ a collection of of subsets of $\Omega$, and $U$ any nonempty set. 
show that the two $\sigma$-fields on $\Omega\times U$, $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\times U$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{C}\times U) $ are equal.

Comment: Do you mean $U$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra? Otherwise what does $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) \times U$ mean? If $U$ is just a set, t hen by $\times$ you must mean the Cartesian product, not product of $\sigma$-algebras. But then the result need not even be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\times U$ is a $\sigma$-field on $\Omega\times U$

Comment: Could you give me your definition of $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) \times U$. I am not familiar with the product of a $\sigma$-algebra with a set. The only definition I know is $\Sigma_1 \times \Sigma_2 := \sigma\{A \times B : A \in \Sigma_1, B \in \Sigma_2 \}$ when $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ are both $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\times U=\{A \times U; A \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to prove here. Because the one to one correspondence between $P(\Omega)$ and $\{A\times U: A\in P(\Omega)\}$ preserves all the relevant set operations.

Comment: Let me explain this in detail. First, as a $\sigma$-field containing $\{A\times U:A\in\mathcal{C}\}$, $\{A\times U:A\in \sigma(\mathcal{C})\}$ contains $\sigma(\{A\times U:A\in\mathcal{C}\})$. Then every element in $\sigma(\{A\times U:A\in\mathcal{C}\})$ is of the form $A\times U$, then $\{A:A\times U\in\sigma(\{A\times U:A\in\mathcal{C}\})\}$ is a $\sigma-$field containing $\mathcal{C}$. So we also have $\sigma(\{A\times U:A\in\mathcal{C}\})$ contains $\{A\times U:A\in \sigma(\mathcal{C})\}$.

Comment: I still cant understand why $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\times U \subset \sigma(\mathcal{C}\times U)$.

Comment: Every element of $\sigma(\mathcal{C}\times U)$ is of the form $A\times U$, right? Then check that $\{A: A\times U\in\sigma(\mathcal{C}\times U)\}$ is a $\sigma$-field containning $\mathcal{C}$, thus it contains $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.